# Frame values of same frames of a videofile in Matlab and Octave are different

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

I am trying to read frames of the same video file in both Matlab and Octave (using OpenCV-Python).

However, both are showing varied matrix values for the same frame when captured. Why is this so?

Screenshots attached.
Matlab frame 3[image]

And

Frame 3 - Open CV Python
Edit 1: Octave is processing images called by OpenCV python
[image]

Comment: One obvious difference in `Matlab` and `Opencv`, would be that one follows `RGB` convention while latter follows `BGR` convention, but your current logs dont seem to fit in this ambiguity as well, the values have large difference with no sign of `RGB` ambiguity. I would recommend you to save the frame from Matlab and OpenCV respectively to see if there is any diff, Also attach the code that you have used to print these logs, there could be some error in accessing the `Mat` pixels on both sides.

Comment: Which is it: Octave or OpenCV Python?

Comment: @beaker It's basically Octave processing images called from a OpenCV python script.